# Code for evaluating perplexity of an LDA topic model

Tags: modeling, text-mining, fitting

I'm working on a research project where we are trying to assess model fit improvement of our LDA model (the basic [Blie et al., 2003 LDA approach (pdf)](http://cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf)). I'm looking for code that allows us to assess the perplexity of our LDA model as we tune it.

I know the R Package [topicmodels](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/index.html) ([Journal of Statistics Software paper for package](http://jstatsoft.org/v40/i13/paper)) has a perplexity function but my PI wants other options outside of R. Any recommendations?

Comment: welcome to the site. Can you provide full links to (i) the paper, (ii) the R package, please?

Comment: StasK, 

Certainly, see below. 

Links to papers 
- LDA: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf

R Package: topicmodels 
- R Package description: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/topicmodels.pdf
- Journal of Statistics Software paper: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i13/paper

Comment: Uhm... I rather wanted you to edit your original question and include links there, so that other folks would not have to dig into the comments. (This is not your typical forum, you can go back and edit your questions. In fact, I can edit it, too, but it would be better if you did.)